# Are all matrices $A$ with $A^T=A^{-1}$ permutation matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices, permutation-matrices

I know that all permutation matrices $A$ satisfy $A^T=A^{-1}$, but is the converse,
all matrices $A$ with $A^T=A^{-1}$ are permutation matrices, also true? I believe it is true, but I haven't been able to confirm it. I know this is probably a very dumb question, but I'm very unsure and just want some clarification.

Comment: Thos matrices are called [orthogonal matrices](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriz_ortogonal)

Comment: This is the definition of an orthogonal matrix. Any square matrix whose columns form an orthonormal basis will be orthogonal, e.g. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1}$.

Comment: Find a counter example by using the formula for the inverse of a $2 \times 2$ matrix and setting it equal to its transpose.

Comment: Or just take a rotation matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\alpha&-\sin\alpha\\\sin\alpha&\cos\alpha\end{pmatrix}\,.$$